# Jquery move elements onclick until a calculated margin is reached, then stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I want to make a short content slider where the navigation buttons add a margin-left to the content-div where the slides are in.

Everything works fine, but I want to stop the animation when a certain margin is reached.

```
var allElements = $('figure').length
var singleWidth= $('figure .contents').width();
var moveMax = allElements * singleWidth
var moveElement = '#sliderwrapper'
var actualMargin = $(moveElement).css('margin-left');


$('#navigation span.next').click(function() {
     if (actualMargin < moveMax) {
        $('#sliderwrapper').animate({"margin-left": '+='+singleWidth});
     }
     else {
        $('#sliderwrapper').stop();
    }
});

$('#navigation  span.previous').click(function() {
     $('#sliderwrapper').animate({"margin-left": '-='+singleWidth});
});
```

If I replace the 'actualMargin'-statement with a number shorter than the calculated 'moveMax' it works and vice versa.

Any ideas?

Thank You!

**EDIT:
Here's a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/am65n/**

Comment: What about instead of adding singleWidth you add the difference? Instead of checking on each animation step - just animate the margin-left to the correct position to begin with? Instead of adding singleWidth, set it to `Math.min(singleWidth+actualMargin,moveMax)` , that is - the smaller between the singleWidth and actual margin, or the maximal position.

Comment: I tried really hard to understand what you mean, but I really don't get it. Can you explain a bit further.
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You could you `step` function in **[jQuery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** which would be called for each animated property of each animated element and implement the code logic into that.

**Example::**

```
$('#sliderwrapper').animate(
    {"margin-left": '+='+singleWidth},
    { 
        step: function( now, fx ) {
            if($(moveElement).css('margin-left') >= moveMax) {
                $('#sliderwrapper').stop();
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: Actually I can't get it to work, same problem.
I created a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/am65n/